# using ord function (ord(B[0]) - ord('0'))

Tags: python

I started learning Python recently. I reading Mark Lutz 4th edition. In a book i saw that code (below). What happens in this code? I dont undesrtand line 4. Can you explain me? Sorry for my bad english.

```
B = '1101'
I = 0
while B != '':
     I = I * 2 + (ord(B[0]) - ord('0'))
     B = B[1:] 
print(I)
```

Comment: `pydoc ord`. By the way, that is some awful Python code.

Comment: Thank you all) Now i undestand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [158]: ord('0')
Out[158]: 48

In [159]: ord('1')
Out[159]: 49
```

So `ord(B[0]) - ord('0')` is the int `1` when `B[0]` is the string `'1'`, and it is the int `0` when `B[0]` is the string `'0'`. In short, it is just a way to convert the string to an int. `int(B[0])` would have been simpler, but the author is avoiding `int`, since if you have `int` then the entire piece of code could be replaced by `int(B, 2)`.

```
In [168]: int(B, 2)
Out[168]: 13
```

So it is good to understand what the code is doing, but 
don't take it as a Pythonic example of how to convert a binary string representation into the corresponding int.

---

```
In [161]: help(ord)
    Return the integer ordinal of a one-character string.
```

---

The line

```
I = I * 2 + (ord(B[0]) - ord('0'))
```

is incrementing `I` so as to convert the string `B` into an `int`. `B` is being interpreted as the binary representation of an `int`, and this code is calculating the value of that `int`.

```
1101 (base 2) = 2**3 + 2**2 + 2**0 = 2*(2*((2*1) + 1) + 0) + 1
```

The while-loop is computing the expression on the right-hand side, starting with the inner-most parenthesized expression first, and working its way out.

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm converts a binary number to its decimal representation. The binary number 1011 is equal to 11 because:

```
1      0      1      1
^      ^      ^      ^
2^3 +  0   +  2^1  + 2^0   = 11
```

So, the computation is made by multiplying I by 2 (shifting to the left in binary) and add 0 or 1.

```
1    ->   1
11   ->   1 * 2 + 1   = 3
011  ->   3 * 2 + 0   = 6
1011 ->   6 * 2 + 1   = 11
```

`ord` is not very useful here: it return the integer ordinal of a one-character string. But, here we want 1 if the string is "1" and 0 if the string is 0. So, using int(B[0]) would be better.

```
>>> ord("1") - ord("0")
1
>>> ord("0") - ord("0")
0
```

#### Bonus: a more Pythonic way

If you like Python, list comprehension and `sum` function, here's a one-liner for the algorithm presented:

```
>>> sum(2**i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(B)) if x == '1')
11
```

But, the best solution is still using `int` built-in method:

```
>>> int(B, base=2)
11
```

Answer (score 0):

`ord(ch)` returns the byte value for a character - "a" is 65, "b" is 66, etc.

If the character is a digit, `ord(ch) - order("0")` returns the numeric value of the digit - "0" becomes o, "1" becomes 1, etc.

The code, overall, parses a strong containing a binary number and collects the value of the number in I.

Comment: ... and, as has been commented, it is unPythonic code, variable names should lowercase, and instead of `while b: b = b[1:]` it should use `for ch in b`, or better yet `int(b, 2)`.